# Accepting a destructured object as the only argument to an arrow function

Tags: ecmascript-6

I have a function accepting a callback and calling it with an object:

```
function login(callback) { 
   /* do login ; */ 
   callback({ username: 'u', email: 'e@e.e' }); 
}
```

If I try:

```
login(obj => { console.log(obj.username); });
```

all is well, but if I try:

```
login({username, email} => { console.log(username); });
```

I get 'VM880:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }(…)'

Why does this not work and how can I get it to work ?

Comment: You need to wrap the destructured parameters in parentheses, i.e. 'login(({...}) => { console.log(...) })'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use parenthesis around the argument for it to be parsed the way you expect. You can only leave off the parenthesis for an arrow function if you have a single identifier on the left side of the `=>` and nothing else:

```
login(({username, email}) => { console.log(username); });
```

https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/2016/#prod-ArrowParameters

Answer (score 3):

The problem is very similar to the case of [starting a statement with a curly brace](https://github.com/nzakas/understandinges6/blob/master/manuscript/05-Destructuring.md).

An opening curly brace marks the start of a code block. But the destructuring object pattern `{username, email}` is not a code block. The parentheses around the destructing pattern forces it to be evaluated as an expression. As Paulpro already mentioned, the solution is to put parenthesis around the object pattern `{username, email}`:

`login(({username, email}) => { console.log(username); });`

Please also see the [pitfalls of destructuring](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_destructuring.html#_pitfalls-of-destructuring)